# How does 'mongodb-server-aggregation' work (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, meteorite, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to perform an aggregation on the server part of my meteor application.
I've installed the [`mongodb-server-aggregation`](https://github.com/zvictor/meteor-mongo-server) package, but when I do a simple aggregation like

```
var cursor = Tasks.aggregate(
    [
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': '$code'
        }
      }
    ]
  );
```

I get the following error

```
...
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined
     at _futureWrapper (packages/mongodb-server-aggregation/server.coffee:17:31)
...
```

I probably do something wrong here, but I must say, I cannot find any examples too. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: What version of **meteor** you're working with? I is it possible that package aouthor has not updated it to the latest version of **meteor**?

Comment: I'm using mrt version `0.7.3` and meteor version `0.8.0.1`

Comment: any idea which version of meteor it supports ?

Comment: It says if(api.versionsFrom !== undefined) api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.1');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the package maybe comment out line 5 in server.coffee

`MongoDB = Npm.require("mongodb")`

Then I think it works.

Also, a bit of a technicality but line 8 has 
`Meteor.Collection` which should be `Mongo.Collection`

If you only need it server side, why use the whole package?   Fork it and then roll your own version.

Comment: Good work, thanks a lot for solving this! I'll check this out as soon I've time! Could you inform the author of this package or create a Pull Request ?

Comment: I don't use the package because I only need server side aggregation..  I used his package as a guideline to write my own server side aggregation method and that is how I know about the issue because I too ran into the problem.